# Div rotate fluctuation on mousedown

Tags: javascript, html, rotation

Div is rotating on mousemove of handle that is the rotate icon on the right of the div, problem is when you click on the icon the div rotates more than it should, this happens only when you click i.e. when you mousedown but rotates smoothly after click. What must be the problem ?

For example if the div is at zero degrees and you click on the rotate icon and move the mouse while mousedown the div moves anticlockwise approx 20 degrees and then the actual smooth movement goes on.

```js
current = null;

var rot = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-undo')[0];
rot.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      initRotate(e)
    }, false);

function initRotate(e) {
    current = document.getElementById('box1');
    var arrowRects = current.getBoundingClientRect();
    clientX = arrowRects.left + arrowRects.width / 2;
    clientY = arrowRects.top + arrowRects.height / 2;
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", rotateStart, false);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", rotateStop, false);
  }

  function rotateStart(e) {
    var radians = Math.atan2(e.clientY - clientY, e.clientX - clientX);
    var deg = radians * (180/Math.PI);
    current.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    current.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    current.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    current.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    current.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    var rect = current.getBoundingClientRect();
    parent = current.parentNode;
    if (parent.classList.contains('drag-drop')) {
      parent.style.width = rect.width;
      parent.style.height = rect.height;
    }
  }

  function rotateStop(e) {
    current = null;
    clientX = 0;
    clientY = 0;
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", rotateStart, false);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", rotateStop, false);
  }
```

```css
#p{
 height:100px;
}

.boxes {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    /* set these so Chrome doesn't return 'auto' from getComputedStyle */
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    /* resize: both; */
    overflow: visible;
    /* z-index: 10; */
    touch-action: none;
    user-select: none;
  }

  .boxes .fa-undo {
    right: -17px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="p"> </div>
<div id="box1" class="boxes" style=""><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 20 to final degree compuation before applying it to tranform rotate css.

```js
current = null;

var rot = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-undo')[0];
rot.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  initRotate(e)
}, false);

function initRotate(e) {
  current = document.getElementById('box1');
  var arrowRects = current.getBoundingClientRect();
  clientX = arrowRects.left + arrowRects.width / 2;
  clientY = arrowRects.top + arrowRects.height / 2;
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", rotateStart, false);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", rotateStop, false);
}

function rotateStart(e) {
  var radians = Math.atan2(e.clientY - clientY, e.clientX - clientX);
  var deg = radians * (180 / Math.PI) + 20;
  current.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  current.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  current.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  current.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  current.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  var rect = current.getBoundingClientRect();
  parent = current.parentNode;
  if (parent.classList.contains('drag-drop')) {
    parent.style.width = rect.width;
    parent.style.height = rect.height;
  }
}

function rotateStop(e) {
  current = null;
  clientX = 0;
  clientY = 0;
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", rotateStart, false);
  window.removeEventListener("mouseup", rotateStop, false);
}
```

```css
#p {
  height: 100px;
}

.boxes {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  /* set these so Chrome doesn't return 'auto' from getComputedStyle */
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* resize: both; */
  overflow: visible;
  /* z-index: 10; */
  touch-action: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.boxes .fa-undo {
  right: -17px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="p"> </div>
<div id="box1" class="boxes" style=""><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```